# Create my own console.log version using closures | Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I want to create my own version of console.log, using a 'curry' function and including the possibility to show or not the logs. ( inspired for SecretsOfTheJavascriptNinja )

So I implemented this function using closures:

```
Function.prototype.conditionalCurry = function() {
   var fn = this;
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   var show = args[0];
   args = args.slice(1, args.length);

   return function() {
      if (show) {
          return fn.apply(this, args.concat(   
                Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
      }
      else return;
   };
};
```

When I tested the code using node in the terminal it works:

```
var newLog = console.log.conditionalCurry(true, 'Always visible|' );
newLog('log visible'); // gives on the console: Always visible| log visible

newLog = console.log.conditionalCurry(false, 'never visible|' );
newLog('log visible'); // gives nothing, it works!
```

But when I test the code on Chrome 48.0.2564.109 and in firefox 44.0.2 arises a problem, and I think is the same in both cases.

As far as I can see, somehow the context 'this' passed to the function conditionalCurry when I use node in terminal, is an anonymous function, but in the case of the browsers 'this' appear as a function called 'log', and I believe this is breaking the code.

Any idea how can I implement this functionality in browsers?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ksv3zot/1/)

Thanks in advance!!!

---

With Bergi's solution, now it works: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ksv3zot/2/)

Comment: Use `console.log.bind(console).conditionalCurry(…)`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi it works out of the box!.  

let me see if I understood. The method log() of the console object, needs access to the context of console to work, what would be their own closure. 

So when I call conditionalCurry on console.log the context that I'm getting and storing in fn variable is the one within log() function. 

So then when I call the newLog, it can't print anything, cause .log doesn't have access to the closures that usually has, cause my fn variable makes reference to the log() context, not the console context...  I am close?? Thanks!

Comment: "*cause .log doesn't have access to the closures that usually has*" - no, closure variables don't matter here (you can mess with them from the outside anyway). It's only important that the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the expected one - a `Console` instance.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, this has been really helpful. Can you post your comment as an answer, to be able to vote it?

Answer (score 1):

I would be weary about modifying the prototype of existing language features such as `Function`. It seems you really want instances of these logging tools back, so you may as well define that instance and use it in the sort of "classical" sense.

For example, let's create a "class" (just to use the language agnostic term) called "Logger". Instances of logger will be able to be configurable to show a prefixed message, conditionally send messages to the log, and also use the log in a semi traditional manner.

```js
function Logger(display,prefix){
  this.display = display == [][0] ? true : display;
  this.prefix = prefix;
}
Logger.prototype.log = function(){
  if(this.display){
    [].splice.apply(arguments,[0,0,this.prefix])
    console.log.apply(console,arguments);  
  }else{
    console.log(this.prefix);
  }
  return this;
};    
Logger.prototype.show = function(truthy){
  this.display = !!truthy;
  return this;
};
Logger.prototype.note = function(msg){
  this.prefix = msg;
  return this;
};

var newLog = new Logger(true,'always |');
newLog.log('show me');//always | show me

newLog.note('never show').show(false);
newLog.log('show me now');//never show
```

Comment: Thanks @Travis, this not directly answer my question, but gives me a good approach to solve the general issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of execution context. Since you attached the curry function to the 'function prototype', the 'this' keyword will reference the function that you are calling it on. In this case, the 'log' in console.log.

I wouldn't modify prototypes, just make a curry helper function :)

```
function curry(fn, ctx) {
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice.call;

  return function f() {
    var x = slice(arguments);
    // If we have enough arguments, call the function
    // You can get the arity with the 'length' property
    if (x.length >= fn.length) return fn.apply(ctx, x);
    // If not, collect more arguments
    return function () {
      var y = slice(arguments);
      return f.apply(null, x.concat(y));
    }
  }
}

// Trivial example
var curriedSum = curry(function(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
});

// this now works
curriedSum(1, 2, 3);
curriedSum(1)(2, 3);
curriedsum(1)(2)(3);



// for your use case
var curriedLog = curry(function(show, prefix, msg) {
  if (! show) return;

  return console.log(prefix + msg);
});

// Use like so
var neverLogs = curriedLog(false);
neverLog('Some Prefix|', 'some message') // never logs

var logWithPrefix = curriedLog(true, 'This is my prefix|');
logWithPrefix('wassup') // logs   'this is my prefix| wassup'
```

If you need to force the 'this' keyword to be a specific object, pass that object as the second parameter.

```
curry(fn, context);
```

Comment: How does your `curry` function solve the problem with the context? Could you please show how it is applicable to the OPs use case (instead of that trivial, not context-dependent sum function)?

Comment: I updated it to take a context as the second argument. And my second sentence explained why the OP's context was wrong.

Comment: Yes, your explanation was fine, but your solution didn't fit. And still doesn't really, imo.

Comment: I'm not offering a solution. I gave an answer, and suggested my own alternative. You're welcome to provide your own answer if you have a different view.

Comment: @Bergi I offered a solution at the bottom, that implements the OP's original functionality.